# Blacklisting won't work for kernel module "radeon"

Tags: kernel-modules, syslinux, modprobe

I tried to blacklist kernel module "radeon" as it is classhing with my propietary drivers. I tried it doing it in two ways but none of them worked and every time command

```
mkinitcpio -M
```

will list "radeon" module.

---

I tried to create file  `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon.config` with lines

```
blacklist radeon
fglrx
```

After reboot this didn't work so I deleted this file and tried to do the same in my bootloader (I am using **syslinux**) kernel line. I edited the file `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg`to look like this:

```
DEFAULT arch
PROMPT 0  
TIMEOUT 10
UI menu.c32

MENU TITLE Arch Linux
#MENU BACKGROUND splash.png
MENU COLOR border       30;44   #40ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR title        1;36;44 #9033ccff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR sel          7;37;40 #e0ffffff #20ffffff all
MENU COLOR unsel        37;44   #50ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR help         37;40   #c0ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout_msg  37;40   #80ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout      1;37;40 #c0ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR msg07        37;40   #90ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR tabmsg       31;40   #30ffffff #00000000 std

LABEL archstudio
    MENU LABEL Linux (Arch) - recording studio
    LINUX ../vmlinuz-linux-rt
    APPEND root=/dev/sda1 rw threadirqs nomodeset modprobe.blacklist=radeon fglrx
    INITRD ../initramfs-linux-rt.img
```

I am using RT kernel "**linux-rt**" so I did rebuild the bootloader using

```
mkinitcpio -p linux-rt
```

After restart I noticed that this didn't work either.

---

Command `mkinitcpio -v` shows that some hooks load "radeon" module:

```
==> Starting dry run: 3.10.14-rt9-1-rt
      -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/base]
    adding file: /bin/busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.18.so
    adding file: /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
    adding symlink: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.18.so
    adding file: /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/[ -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/[[ -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ash -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/awk -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/basename -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/cat -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/chgrp -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/chmod -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/chown -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/chroot -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/clear -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/cp -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/cttyhack -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/cut -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/dd -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/df -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/dirname -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/dmesg -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/du -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/echo -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/egrep -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/env -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/expr -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/false -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/free -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/getopt -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/grep -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/halt -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/head -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/hexdump -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ifconfig -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/init -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/install -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ip -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ipaddr -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/iplink -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/iproute -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/iprule -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/iptunnel -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/kbd_mode -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/kill -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/killall -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/less -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ln -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/loadfont -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/loadkmap -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/losetup -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ls -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/md5sum -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mkdir -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mkfifo -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mknod -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mktemp -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mountpoint -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/mv -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/nc -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/netstat -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/nslookup -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/openvt -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/pgrep -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/pidof -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ping -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ping6 -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/poweroff -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/printf -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/ps -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/pwd -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/readlink -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/reboot -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/rm -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/rmdir -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/route -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sed -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/seq -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/setfont -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sh -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sha1sum -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sha256sum -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sha512sum -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sleep -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sort -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/stat -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/strings -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/sync -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/tac -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/tail -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/telnet -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/test -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/tftp -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/touch -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/true -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/umount -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/uname -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/uniq -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/uptime -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/vi -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/wc -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/wget -> busybox
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/yes -> busybox
    adding file: /usr/sbin/kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
    adding file: /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/depmod -> kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/insmod -> kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/rmmod -> kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/lsmod -> kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/modprobe -> kmod
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/modinfo -> kmod
    adding file: /usr/sbin/blkid
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/lib/libblkid.so.1.1.0
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    adding file: /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
    adding file: /usr/sbin/mount
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/lib/libmount.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/sbin/switch_root
    adding file: /init_functions
    adding file: /init
    adding file: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/usb-load-ehci-first.conf
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/udev]
    adding file: /etc/udev/udev.conf
    adding file: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.18.so
    adding file: /usr/lib/librt-2.18.so
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.2.6
    adding file: /usr/lib/libkmod.so.2.2.6
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/lib/libacl.so.1.1.0
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.18.so
    adding file: /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
    adding file: /usr/bin/udevadm
    adding file: /usr/bin/systemd-tmpfiles
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
    adding file: /usr/lib/libcap.so.2.24
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/ata_id
    adding file: /usr/lib/udev/scsi_id
    adding file: /hooks/udev
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/autodetect]
libkmod: kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with 'fglrx'
    caching 37 modules
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/modconf]
    adding dir: /etc/modprobe.d
    adding file: /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf
    adding file: /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
    overwriting file: /usr/lib/modprobe.d/usb-load-ehci-first.conf
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/block]
    adding module: scsi_mod
    adding module: sd_mod
    adding module: cdrom
    adding module: sr_mod
    adding module: libata
    adding module: pata_amd
    adding module: sata_nv
    adding module: pata_acpi
    adding module: ata_generic
    adding module: usb-common
    adding module: usbcore
    adding module: ohci_hcd
    adding module: ehci-hcd
    adding module: ehci_pci
    adding module: usb_storage
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/filesystems]
    adding module: mbcache
    adding module: jbd2
    adding module: crc16
    adding module: ext4
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/keyboard]
    adding module: hid
    adding module: hid_generic
    adding module: usbhid
  -> Running build hook: [/usr/lib/initcpio/install/fsck]
    adding file: /usr/sbin/fsck.ext4
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    adding file: /usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2.4
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    adding file: /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2.1
    adding symlink: /usr/lib/libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    adding file: /usr/lib/libe2p.so.2.3
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/fsck.ext2 -> fsck.ext4
    adding symlink: /usr/bin/fsck.ext3 -> fsck.ext4
    adding file: /usr/sbin/fsck
    adding module: i2c-core
    adding module: drm
    adding module: drm_kms_helper
    adding module: ttm
    adding module: i2c-algo-bit
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R520_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RS600_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RS690_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R420_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R300_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R200_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R100_cp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO2_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO2_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PALM_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PALM_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R700_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R600_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV710_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV730_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV770_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RS780_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV670_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV635_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV620_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV630_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV610_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R600_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/R600_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/ARUBA_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/ARUBA_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/ARUBA_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAYMAN_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAYMAN_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAYMAN_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAYMAN_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAICOS_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAICOS_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CAICOS_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TURKS_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TURKS_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TURKS_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/BTC_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/BARTS_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/BARTS_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/BARTS_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/HAINAN_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/HAINAN_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/HAINAN_ce.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/HAINAN_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/HAINAN_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/OLAND_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/OLAND_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/OLAND_ce.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/OLAND_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/OLAND_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_ce.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/VERDE_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_ce.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/PITCAIRN_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_rlc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_mc.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_ce.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_me.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_pfp.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/TAHITI_uvd.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_uvd.bin
    adding file: /usr/lib/firmware/radeon/RV710_uvd.bin
    adding module: radeon
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Dry run complete, use -g IMAGE to generate a real image
```

Some hooks start the "radeon" module but how do I prevent them to? This is first time I am dealing with hooks. I checked and no files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` nor `/etc/modules-load.d/` start the "radeon"...

Comment: I noticed that I have to do setup differently for a custom kernel like "**linux-rt**" which I use. So I reinstalled Catalyst like described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst#Custom_kernels When reinstalling I had to delete previous **catalyst** and **catalyst-utils** and a package called **ati-dri** and now module "radeon" isn't loaded at boot anymore. I installed this package only: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/catalyst-total-hd234k/ Could it be that ati-dri had been loading module "radeon" by itself?

Comment: Did you solve this? Please share your solution with us ☺

Comment: I never managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. modprobe.d/*.conf files are (mainly) for blacklists and if you just add a module name like fglrx then the rest of that config file gets ignored (which is your issue). So remove fglrx from the modprobe.d/radeon.conf file and add it to /etc/modules (point #2):
2. If you want to explicitly load modules /etc/modules should suffice.
3. Rename the radeon.config (-> .config) to 00-radeon.conf (-> .conf) or 00-blacklist-radeon.conf so it gets parsed first
4. Could also try adding FILES="/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf" to your mkinitcpio.conf
5. Last resort add MODULES="fglrx" into the mkinitcpio.conf (it loads that module before any other)

Comment: The 3rd tip helped. Didn't know, that they are executed ordered by name and that the order is important

Comment: This problem was never solved for me as I already reinstalled my PC, but 3rd tip really is nice!

Answer (score 1):

The blacklist command will blacklist a module so that it will not be loaded automatically, but the module may be loaded if another non-blacklisted module depends on it or if it is loaded manually.

However, there is a workaround for this behaviour; the install command instructs modprobe to run a custom command instead of inserting the module in the kernel as normal, so you can force the module to always fail loading with, by inserting below line to */etc/modprobe.d/radeon.config*

```
install radeon /bin/false
```

This will effectively blacklist that module and any other that depends on it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help either still

Comment: What about systemd-modules-load? How come if I blacklist something on the kernel command line, systemd doesn't recognise it?

Answer (score 0):

kernel parameters must be in the form

```
xxxxx=yyyy
```

with no spaces in `xxxxx` or `yyyy`. In my experience, quotes/escaping cannot be used either.
So

```
modprobe.blacklist=radeon fglrx
```

will be parsed as `modprobe.blacklist=radeon` and another kernel parameter of 'fglrx' which will be ignored as it will not be recognised as a valid parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `blacklist radeon` you have to add it to the conf file and then issue the command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```